# CQ Dispatcher user authentication

Tags: aem

Can anybody helpme how do we implement user session management from the dispatcher level ? everything working fine from the publish server, but seeing weird behavior from web server. though I logout, still session maintains at browser cache. I have code below  in my dispatcher.any file and also authorization set to zero using   /allowAuthorized "0" under /cache section

/sessionmanagement

{

/directory "/opt/cq/www/htdocs/publish/.sessions"

/header "Cookie:login-token"

/timeout "3000"

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to create two farm for same site. One is for secure (logged in state) and another for normal state.

1. Normal state farm wont have authorize flag
2. Secure state farm will have authorize flag and session configuration
3. Both farms will have separate cache folder

Reference:

1. https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/administer/security/cug.html
2. https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/dispatcher/disp-config.html